Transfer token2022 to a address with anchor program
One of the function in my anchor program basically transferring SPL Token to a wallet address.
But when dealing with token2022, it doesn't work. It shows error
Error Code: AccountOwnedByWrongProgram. Error Number: 3087. Error Message: The given account is owned by a different program than expected

May i know is anyone here have experience transfer token2022 to wallet address before?
Below is my program code
## THE INSTRUCTIONS

use anchor_lang::{prelude::*, solana_program::entrypoint::ProgramResult};

use anchor_spl::associated_token;
use anchor_spl::token::{self, Token, TokenAccount, Transfer};
use crate::state::*;

pub fn handler(ctx: Context<DepositStake>, amount: u64, reference: String) -> ProgramResult {
    // Transfer tokens
    let cpi_accounts = Transfer {
        from: ctx.accounts.from_token_account.to_account_info(),
        to: ctx.accounts.to_token_account.to_account_info(),
        authority: ctx.accounts.user.to_account_info(),
    };
    let cpi_program = ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info();
    let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new(cpi_program, cpi_accounts);
    token::transfer(cpi_ctx, amount)?;
    emit!(Stake {
        reference,
        amount,
        user: *ctx.accounts.user.to_account_info().key,
    });
    Ok(())
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct DepositStake<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub token_mint: Account<'info, token::Mint>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub from_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = user,
        associated_token::mint = token_mint,
        associated_token::authority = staking_wallet,
    )]
    pub to_token_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,
    #[account(constraint = staking_wallet.key() == global_data.staking_wallet.key())]
    pub staking_wallet: SystemAccount<'info>,
    #[account(seeds = [b"global-data"], bump)]
    pub global_data: Account<'info, GlobalData>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, associated_token::AssociatedToken>,
}

#[event]
pub struct Stake {
    pub reference: String,
    pub amount: u64,
    pub user: Pubkey,
}

The entry
pub mod instructions;
pub mod state;

use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_lang::solana_program::entrypoint::ProgramResult;
use instructions::*;

declare_id!("xxxx");

#[program]
pub mod custom_staking {
    use super::*;

    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>, staking_wallet: Pubkey) -> ProgramResult {
        instructions::initialize::handler(ctx, staking_wallet)
    }

    pub fn deposit_stake(
        ctx: Context<DepositStake>,
        amount: u64,
        reference: String,
    ) -> ProgramResult {
        instructions::deposit_stake::handler(ctx, amount, reference)
    }

  
}


Please share the code for this invocation

@Jimii Hi, I just added the code snippet for reference

If you want your program to work with both SPL Token and SPL Token 2022, you'll need to use the Interface variants for programs and accounts, that way the ownership check allows for both programs. Here's how you'll need to change your accounts:
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct DepositStake<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub token_mint: InterfaceAccount<'info, token_interface::Mint>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub from_token_account: InterfaceAccount<'info, token_interface::TokenAccount>,
    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = user,
        associated_token::mint = token_mint,
        associated_token::authority = staking_wallet,
    )]
    pub to_token_account: InterfaceAccount<'info, token_interface::TokenAccount>,
    #[account(constraint = staking_wallet.key() == global_data.staking_wallet.key())]
    pub staking_wallet: SystemAccount<'info>,
    #[account(seeds = [b"global-data"], bump)]
    pub global_data: Account<'info, GlobalData>,
    pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
    pub token_program: Interface<'info, token_interface::TokenInterface>,
    pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, associated_token::AssociatedToken>,
}

Adapted from https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/d6b6ac7a4d4920e418a613815bf9c8057d44a609/tests/spl/token-wrapper/programs/token-wrapper/src/lib.rs#L154

Thanks for the insightful sharing, I will definitely try out & upvote your answer later
